# Incompatible function declaration

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm stuck, why am i getting an error: declaration is incompatible...

'void A::function(int,int,std::vector<_Ty> *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'A'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Point
1>          ]

```
//cpp file
void A::function(int a, int b, vector<B> *p)
{    

}

//header file

class B
{
public:
     int q;
};
class A
{     
public:    
     void function(int a, int b, vector<B> *p);    
};
```

Comment: Call is now same as prototype yet still there is an error

Comment: Can you post the `A::function` decleration in cpp file? And why is class B there?

Comment: Edit: the function is protected

Comment: You cannot call a protected function (except within the class or sons and friends). Protecting a function is a way to allow you to prevent calling it (except in the mentioned places) and let it be inherited.

Comment: Edit: function is now public with error

Comment: Please Post the error if possible.

Comment: void A::function(int,int,std::vector<_Ty> *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'A' error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'

Comment: Add `#include <vector>`.

Comment: as sad_man said, add `#include <vector>` then `using namespace std;` to the header file. also perhaps you have written `void A::function(int,int,std::vector<_Ty> *)` instead of `void A::function(int,int,std::vector<B> *)` in a place.

Comment: Added using namespace std to header and it works thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the header of the function should be exactly the same.

```
//cpp file 
void A::function(int a, int b, vector<B>* c) { }  

//header file  
Class B {
public:
    int q; 
}; 
class A {
public:
    void function(int a, int b, vector<B> *line);     
};
```

or :

```
//cpp file 
void A::function(int a, int b, vector<B>& c) { }  

//header file  
Class B {
public:
    int q;
};
class A {
public:
    void function(int a, int b, vector<B> &line);     
};
```

However, when calling the function in the first case, you should replace the `*` with `&` if passing an object, so the local pointer will get the address of the passed object. Or manually pass a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Problems!!!!

`void function(int a, int b, vector<B> *line);` and `void function(int a, int b, vector<B> & line);` are two different signatures (function prototypes).

More importantly there is no such keyword `Class` in C++.

Comment: I would have been first if it wasn't for that stupid captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you're missing a semicolon at the end of `B`.  Additionally, you're using `Class` instead of `class`.

For the signature itself, your declaration (in the header file) takes a pointer to a `vector` while your definition (in the `.cpp` file) takes a reference.

```
//cpp file
void A::function(int a, int b, vector<B>& c) // // Arguments are an int, an int, and a vector<B> reference.
{    

}

//header file

class B
{
public:
     int q;
};

class A
{     
public:    
     void function(int a, int b, vector<B>& line);
        // Same arguments.
};
```